# Using Socket-Io with react

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use namespaces with a socket-io server and a react client.

Client

```
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const testSocket = io(`http://localhost:3001/poker`);
        console.log(testSocket)
        setSocket(testSocket);
        return () => testSocket.close();
    }, [setSocket]);
```

Server

```
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log('connection');
    });

    const test = io.of("/test");

    test.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log("here2");
    });
```

When I do this the console.log() on the client returns
`Object { connected: false, disconnected: true, receiveBuffer: [], sendBuffer: [], ids: 0, acks: {}, flags: {}, io: {…}, nsp: "/test", subs: (4) […] }`
and on the server side it says "connection" every few seconds but it never triggers the namespace.
The requests the browser sends every few seconds have a polling transport rather than a socket so it might just not be connection but I can't figure out why, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting {transports: ["websocket"]} on the client seems to have done the trick.